# Security stripInaccessible's SObjectAccessDecision getRecords() ordering

Tags: apex, security

Is there a guarantee documented anywhere that the ordering of the SObjectAccessDescision's getRecords() method will match the ordering of the input list?

It seems to be the behavior but I can't see any explicit documentation concerning the ordering.

```
List<Account> accs = new List<Account>();
for (String name : new List<String> { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }) {
    Account a = new Account(Name = name);
}

// passing true as the third parameter guarantees the length of the returned list is equal
// to the input list (otherwise exception is thrown) but no guarantee on the ordering?
List<Account> strippedAccounts = Security.stripInaccessible(System.AccessType.UPDATABLE, accs, true).getRecords();
for (Integer i = 0; i < strippedAccounts.size(); i++) {
    System.assertEquals(strippedAccounts[i].Name, accs[i].Name);
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_SObjectAccessDecision.htm#topic-title

> getRecords()
>
> Returns a list of new sObjects that are identical to the source records, except that they are stripped of fields that fail the field-level security check for the current user.

Can't tell if 'identical' applies to individual records or the list as a whole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is never as explicit as this (unfortunately). However, it is nevertheless true. The ordering of the records in the list will be preserved. This is also true for other methods that return lists of objects that don't appear to guarantee order (e.g. Database.insert will return SaveResult objects in the same order as the original DML list).

Comment: The documentation should be as explicit as this, and indeed is for [handling of DML SaveResults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm) vs the input list, for example. This is a significant oversight in the documentation for this new feature.

Comment: This is great to know. Having the ordering preserved is essential especially during an insert operation. Otherwise there's no way to set the ID field on the unstripped copy of the records.

Comment: @PhilW Oh, that looks relatively new... or maybe I'm just misremembering. Either way, good to see that something like that does somewhere, I have something to reference in the future.